# How can I make visual studio use the same powershell that Github for windows does

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-2012, github-for-windows, posh-git

I'm using Github for windows for a non-github project and I am using its powershell prompt.

I'd like to configure visual studio to use the same prompt (via package manager).

I'd also like to not have to install poshgit separately and maintain 2 installations as the github one has pretty much the exact settings I want.

I've seen it is possible to modify the profile that nuget uses for its powershell prompt but I cant find where GH4W stores its settings for poshgit.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm confused. "Posh-git" is one of the Spice Girls, right? Is GH4W is one of the robots from Star Wars?  Or is it a cable TV channel specializing in video games?  SUGGESTION: do a filesystem search for ".gitattributes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your `NuGet_profile.ps1`:

```
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
. $env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn the problem sideways, so I would make GitHub for Windows use the same Powershell prompt that Visual Studio does. Based on my experiences with Visual Studio and with git, I think that would be the easier task and the task more likely to succeed.